# AngularJS : Call controller function from outside with vm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

Here I have :

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller("myController", function () {
        var vm = this;
        vm.myFunction = function() { alert('foo'); };
});

app.animation('.animate', ["$timeout", function($timeout) {
      var vm = this;
      return {
        addClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log('this is displayed');
                vm.myFunction(); // Doesn't work !
            });
        }
      }
}]);
```

When I add a class in the template, `addClass` gets fired. However, `vm.myFunction()` doesn't, because it does not exist.

How do we do this in angular ?

Comment: what kind of syntax for a controller this is... where is the controller name?

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to put in in the sample !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some different from yours but I thought this can help you...

```
in HTML

<div id="outer" ng-controller="myController"></div>

in JS

var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

 $scope.myFunction = function() { alert('foo'); };

});

var scope = angular.element($("#outer")).scope();
scope.myFunction();
```

Comment: I actually found the same answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887872/how-to-trigger-a-controller-function-after-an-animation-in-angular-js and that did the trick ! Thanks !

Comment: Although getting the `scope` by hack, will do, but this is not the best practice that one should followed. If one needs to call the function, then why shouldn't one make use of angular in pure. There are many in it like -> `providers`, `services`, `factory`, etc. which does the job. In your case, it is recommend to make use of either of these.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as the following:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.myFunction = function() { alert('foo'); };
        $scope = vm;
});

app.animation('.animate', ["$timeout", 'myController', function($timeout, myController) {
      var vm = myController;
      return {
        addClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log('this is displayed');
                vm.myFunction(); // Doesn't work !
            });
        }
      }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I did your changes, but I got the following error : "`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myController <- myController <- .animate-animation`"

Comment: Maybe this is because "Attempting to inject one controller into another will also throw an Unknown provider error" from https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr

Comment: Since you haven't shared the demo of your code, it was impossible for me to check and verify the same. You can check in my answers, I most of the time support my code with a working demo. it might have created issue due to some missing module or error.